# JQuery to dynamically update totals

Tags: javascript, jquery

Each time a new `div` is created via a button click, I want to dynamically keep an order so when one div is created it becomes *1 of 1*, then *1 of 2* when a further div is created and when a div is deleted it reverts back to *1 of 1* etc.

I've tried using `each` to update all specific tags, but they do not update themselves each time a new div is added. This is the code:

```js
iadd = 0;
itotal = 0;


$('#add').click(function() {
  iadd++;
  $('<div class="input-group col-sm-offset-4 col-sm-3" name="music" id="music' + iadd + '"><label for="phone" class="control-label"><b>Track ' + iadd + ' of ' + itotal + '</b></label><input type="text" class="form-control" name="music1" placeholder="Email" value="" id="music1" data-name="musicAdd" /><br><input type="text" class="form-control" name="email2" placeholder="Description" value="" id="music2" data-name="emailDesc"/></div>').appendTo('#musics');
  $('.control-label').each(function() {
    itotal = iadd;
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="add">Add</button>
<div class="form-group" id="musics"></div>
```

How could it be possible to enable this? This is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hs7eo879/)

Comment: You don't actually need a counter variable. Just use `$(selector).length`.

Comment: And to get the current index (when setting the `id`), you could use `$(selector).index()`.

Comment: Go with what @MelanciaUK said and just calculate on the fly.

Comment: Tip: `button` doesn't have a `type=button` attribute.

Comment: Have you considered underscore.js template usage for your task?

Comment: You are welcome. Underscore can help you a lot with dynamic markup. For example, you could write `_.template("<div id='music<%=id%>'>...</div>")({id: 1})` instead of a long string with concatenation. Here is a link for documentation: http://underscorejs.org/#template

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would go like this:

```js
$(function () {
    $('#add').on('click', function () {
        // The total is the number of divs within the main container + 1.
        // + 1 because we're calculating it before actually appending the new one.
        var total = $('#musics div').length + 1;
        // The current index is exactly the total (you could save a variable here).
        var index = total;

        // Create the new div and append it to the main container.
        var newDiv = $('<div class="input-group col-sm-offset-4 col-sm-3" name="music" id="music' + index + '"><label for="phone" class="control-label"><b>Track ' + index + ' of ' + total + '</b></label><input type="text" class="form-control" name="music1" placeholder="Email" value="" id="music1" data-name="musicAdd" /><br><input type="text" class="form-control" name="email2" placeholder="Description" value="" id="music2" data-name="emailDesc"/></div>').appendTo('#musics');
        
        // Loop through the new div siblings (filtering the type just to make sure),
        // and update their labels with the index/total.
        newDiv.siblings('div').each(function (ix, el) {
            $('label', el).html('<b>Track ' + (ix + 1) + ' of ' + total + '</b>');
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="add">Add</button>
<div class="form-group" id="musics"></div>
```

[Demo (jsFiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/MelanciaUK/q0mt2qu7/1/)

...

If you want to go a bit further (with some `prototype`):

```
// The explanation for the code below is basically the same you can
// find in the code above, with the exception of using prototype
// to create a format method, where you replace items within a string.

String.prototype.format = function () {
    var value = this.toString();

    for (var i = 0, len = arguments.length; i < len; i++) {
        value = value.replace(new RegExp('\{[' + i + ']\}', 'g'), arguments[i]);
    }

    return value;
}

String.format = function () {
    if (arguments.length == 0) return '';

    var value = arguments[0].toString();
    for (var i = 1, len = arguments.length; i < len; i++) {
        value = value.replace(new RegExp('\{[' + (i - 1) + ']\}', 'g'), arguments[i]);
    }

    return value;
}

$(function () {
    $('#add').on('click', function () {
        var total = $('#musics div').length + 1;
        var index = total;
        var labelHtml = '<b>Track {0} of {1}</b>';

        var newDiv = $('<div class="input-group col-sm-offset-4 col-sm-3" name="music" id="music{0}"><label for="phone" class="control-label">' + labelHtml.format(index, total) + '</label><input type="text" class="form-control" name="music1" placeholder="Email" value="" id="music1" data-name="musicAdd" /><br><input type="text" class="form-control" name="email2" placeholder="Description" value="" id="music2" data-name="emailDesc"/></div>'.format(index)).appendTo('#musics');

        newDiv.siblings('div').each(function (ix, el) {
            $('label', el).html(labelHtml.format((ix + 1), total));
        });
    });
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MelanciaUK/q0mt2qu7/2/)

...

**UPDATE**

As per your comment, I believe you're planning to have a delete `button` to be able to remove tracks and then update the indexes/total.

You can do it like this:

```js
$(function () {
    // A single function to update the tracks indexes/total.
    function sortTracks() {
        // Not like the first piece of code in the beginning of the answer,
        // here we don't add 1 to the length, because the elements will be
        // already in place.
        var $tracks = $('#musics .input-group');
        var total = $tracks.length;
        
        $tracks.each(function (ix, el) {
            $('label', el).html('<b>Track ' + (ix + 1) + ' of ' + total + '</b>');
        });
    }
    
    $('#add').on('click', function () {
        var index = $('#musics div').length + 1;

        $('<div class="input-group col-sm-offset-4 col-sm-3" name="music" id="music' + index + '"><label for="phone" class="control-label"></label><input type="text" class="form-control" name="music1" placeholder="Email" value="" id="music1" data-name="musicAdd" /><br><input type="text" class="form-control" name="email2" placeholder="Description" value="" id="music2" data-name="emailDesc"/><button class="delete">Delete</button></div>').appendTo('#musics');
        
        sortTracks();        
    });
    
    $('#musics').on('click', '.delete', function () {
        // Remove this element's immediate parent with class = input-group.
        $(this).closest('.input-group').remove();
        
        sortTracks();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="add">Add</button>
<div class="form-group" id="musics"></div>
```

[Demo (jsFiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/MelanciaUK/q0mt2qu7/8/)

**Note:** If you check your `HTML` `string` used to create the *tracks*, you'll notice that your `inputs` have hard-coded `ids`, so you'll have multiple elements sharing the same `id`, which is wrong. `IDs` should be always unique.

Comment: No problems. I'm glad I could help.

Comment: Good answer and a good idea about the `format()` function. But it also could be good to use underscore.js template instead. And move this `div` into something like `<script id='template' type='text\template'><div>...</div></script>`

Comment: @MelanciaUK, when trying to delete a `div` and then updating the index and total values; I tried doing `$(document).on('click','.delete', function() {    
    $(this).closest('.form-group').remove();//remove
    
     var total = $('#musics div').length + 1;
     var index = total;
    
       newDiv('div').each(function (ix, el) {
           $('label', el).html('<b>Track ' + (ix + 1) + ' of ' + total + '</b>');
       });   
 });`. This doesn't however update the values, what would be wrong here?

Comment: This `$(this).closest('.form-group').remove();` will remove the whole container. Is this what you want?